# I can't get data from my <Option> tag in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have a modal form and an slicer for posting the modal data to my endpoint api. this form includes category and subcategories and my problem is with this part. that when i log the form to console, the category and subcategory is undefined,

this is my modal, category and subcategory gets undefined when I submit the form data,

```
type here  function onAddProduct(data, event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    data = { ...data, images: [...data.images] };

    console.log(data);

    handleOpen();

    toast.success("product added");

    const form = new FormData();
    for (const key in data) {
      const value = data[key];
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        value.forEach((v) => {
          form.append(key, v);
        });
      } else {
        form.append(key, value);
      }
    }
    dispatch(postProducts(form)).catch((error) => {
      console.error("Failed to post product:", error);
    });
  }

  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(!open);

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={handleOpen} color="blue" variant="gradient">
        Add Product
      </Button>
      <Dialog open={open} handler={handleOpen}>
        <DialogHeader>Add Your Product</DialogHeader>
        <DialogBody>
          <form
            className="w-full h-50 flex flex-col content-center gap-2"
            onSubmit={handleSubmit(onAddProduct, onError)}
          >
            <Input
              {...register("images", {
                required: "this field is reqired",
              })}
              type="file"
              label="Image:"
              name="images"
            />
            {errors?.images && (
              <p className="text-red-900 text-xs font-light relative animate-bounce">
                This field is required
              </p>
            )}
            <Input
              {...register("name", {
                required: "this field is required",
              })}
              type="text"
              label="Product:"
              name="name"
            />
            {errors?.name && (
              <p className="text-red-900 text-xs font-light relative animate-bounce">
                This field is required
              </p>
            )}
            <div className="flex gap-2">
              <Select>
                {cat.map(({ name, _id }) => (
                  <Option {...register("category")} name="category" key={_id}>
                    {name}
                  </Option>
                ))}
              </Select>
              <Select>
                {subCat.map(({ name, _id }) => (
                  <Option
                    {...register("subcategory")}
                    name="subcategory"
                    key={_id}
                  >
                    {name}
                  </Option>
                ))}
              </Select>

this is my thunk : 
export const postProducts = createAsyncThunk(
  "addProduct/postProduct",
  async (p, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await privateAxios.post(
        "http://localhost:8000/api/products",
        p,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        }
      );
      const goods = response.data;
      console.log(goods);
      return goods;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);
```